# PopUpAnchor - conflict between "click" and "mouseDownOutside" event handlers

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have a PopUpAnchor to display some content. I added a `mouseDownOutside` event handler so if the user clicks outside the popup content, the popup content will be hidden. That works fine.

I would also like the button which controls showing the popup to function as a toggle, so that if the popup content is being displayed and the button clicked, the content will be hidden.

What is happening in the code below is that with the popup content showing, if the button is clicked, the `mouseDownOutside` event handler gets called and then the `click` handler so that the popup content is hidden and then shown again.

Is there a way I can resolve this without complexity (e.g. adding and removing eventListeners on the fly)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       width="1024" height="768">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.events.FlexMouseEvent;


            protected function managePopup(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                if (popupContent.isPopUp == false){
                    trace("managePopup -- opening");
                    popUp.displayPopUp = true;

                } else {
                    trace("managePopup -- closing");
                    popUp.displayPopUp = false;
                }
            }
        ]]>
        </fx:Script>

        <s:Group x="10" y="10">
            <!-- Button used to open PopUp -->
            <s:Button id="openBtn" label="Open PopUp" 
                      click="managePopup(event)"/>

            <!-- PopUpAnchor component set to same size as openBtn to ensure that
            popUp will be positioned relative to the button -->
            <s:PopUpAnchor id="popUp" 
                           popUpPosition="right" 
                           width="92" height="21">
                <!-- BorderContainer to hold popUp contents -->
                <s:BorderContainer id="popupContent" 
                                   mouseDownOutside="managePopup(event)">            
                    <s:layout>
                        <s:VerticalLayout paddingTop="5" 
                                          paddingLeft="5" 
                                          paddingBottom="5" 
                                          paddingRight="5"/>
                    </s:layout>
                    <s:Form>                                            
                        <s:FormItem label="Name :">
                            <s:TextInput/>
                        </s:FormItem>                                            
                        <s:FormItem label="E-Mail :">
                            <s:TextInput/>
                        </s:FormItem>
                    </s:Form>                            
                    <s:HGroup>                                                                
                        <!-- Button used to close popUp -->
                        <s:Button label="CLOSE" click="managePopup(event)"/>
                    </s:HGroup>                
                </s:BorderContainer>                        
            </s:PopUpAnchor>    
        </s:Group>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you are looking for using [`MouseEvent.relatedObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#relatedObject) which give you the display list object to the pointing device now points, and if it's your `openBtn` button so you can exit the function and the button will close the popup. Of course, you should verify if the `MouseEvent.currentTarget` is the `BorderContainer` component and that your `openBtn` is the new target of the mouse.

For that, you can do like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       width="1024" height="768">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.events.FlexMouseEvent;            

            protected function managePopup(event:MouseEvent):void
            {                   
                if (popupContent.isPopUp == false){

                    openBtn.label = "Close PopUp";
                    popUp.displayPopUp = true;

                } else {

                    if(event.currentTarget){
                        if(event.relatedObject){
                            if(event.currentTarget.name == "popup_border" && 
                               event.relatedObject.name == "open_close_btn"
                            ){
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    openBtn.label = "Open PopUp";
                    popUp.displayPopUp = false;

                }

            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Group x="10" y="10">
        <!-- Button used to open PopUp -->
        <s:Button id="openBtn" label="Open PopUp" name="open_close_btn"
                  click="managePopup(event)"/>

        <!-- PopUpAnchor component set to same size as openBtn to ensure that
        popUp will be positioned relative to the button -->
        <s:PopUpAnchor id="popUp" 
                       popUpPosition="right" 
                       width="92" height="21">
            <!-- BorderContainer to hold popUp contents -->
            <s:BorderContainer id="popupContent" mouseDownOutside="managePopup(event)" name="popup_border">            
                <s:layout>
                    <s:VerticalLayout paddingTop="5" 
                                      paddingLeft="5" 
                                      paddingBottom="5" 
                                      paddingRight="5"/>
                </s:layout>
                <s:Form>                                            
                    <s:FormItem label="Name :">
                        <s:TextInput/>
                    </s:FormItem>                                            
                    <s:FormItem label="E-Mail :">
                        <s:TextInput/>
                    </s:FormItem>
                </s:Form>                            
                <s:HGroup>                                                                
                    <!-- Button used to close popUp -->
                    <s:Button label="CLOSE" click="managePopup(event)"/>
                </s:HGroup>                
            </s:BorderContainer>                        
        </s:PopUpAnchor>    
    </s:Group>  
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great! Hadn't heard of the `MouseEvent.relatedObject` before. Also I tend to use `id` and not `name` but I guess `id` is a Flex only thing since `event.relatedObject.id` throws an error.